# MacBook Pro HDD in Gparted - Main partition "unknown"

Tags: partition, hdd, hfs+

I've been given a defective MacBook Pro, seems to be a model from around 2011 - still has a DVD-Drive and a normal HDD.

The MacBook had water spilled over it; so I disassemed it and took the HDD out to connect it (via SATA) to a normal PC. I booted into PartedMagic (with the ultimate Boot CD) and tried to see what's on the HDD.
I can see three partitions:
1: 200MiB fat32; labeled "EFI"
2: 465GiB "unknown", labeled "Customer" 
3: 620MiB hfs+ Recocery_HD

As far as my understanding goes, the user partition should be hfs+ also; when I try to manually mount it (mount -t hfs plus /dev/......) I get an error that it's not possible (wrong filesystem etc).

Has this to do with some kind of encryption?
Is there a way to get the data from the (obviously working) HDD without using another Mac?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Lars

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the system you are running GPARTED from is configured.

It has been quite a while since I have used the Ultimate Boot CD but if I remember correctly it did not have built-in support for HFS+ filesystems. In other words GPARTED will work with HFS+ partitions (create, modify, delete, etc.) but I am unsure that it supports mounting an HFS+ filesystem.

The Ultimate Boot CD Wiki has **no listings** when searching for "HFS." Literally nothing comes up. So either their search function is completely messed up or that CD does not offer HFS+ file system support.

And if trying to mount that file system fails with an error it seems likely that there is no HFS+ support on that CD.

Depending on how Linux knowledgeable you are there are HFS+ filesystem implementations available for Linux that you may be able to install on the Ultimate Boot CD but tht would be outside my area of expertise and outside the remit of AskDifferent. Perhaps over on https://superuser.com/